No Sound/ Blacklist
I have the no audio dummy output issues with my HP omen and the threads I see suggest blacklist snd_soc_avs in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and I have no idea how to do this. I am fairly new to Linux. Help would be greatly appreciated.
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
wendell@wendell-OMEN-T

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
